# How pull Wordpress blog data using Blogger API

Tags: wordpress, web-applications, google-api, blogger, google-data-api

Wordpress mentioned that it supports Blogger API ([link](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Blogger_API)). So, can anyone tell me how to use Blogger API (using python) v3 to pull wordpress public blogs data.

Or, is there any wordpress API to pull public data from its blogs? (Lang: Python).

Any useful documentation that clearly explains the procedure would also be appreciated.